# php syntax - how to concatenate properly - echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory)

Tags: php, css, bloginfo

This is driving me batty. Is my syntax wrong? Why is the first "." in my img src call throwing out an error? This works if I put a hard link in the img src call, FYI.

```
    <a class="blog-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
            the_post_thumbnail('medium-size');
        } else {
            echo '<img src="' . bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); . '/img/ogpimage.png" alt="Blog Posts Placeholder">';
        } ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: Dave is right about the semicolon; however, to catenate, use 'get_bloginfo()' https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/#more-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `bloginfo()` does already an `echo`. It will be printed before everything else in your `echo` statement. Use `get_bloginfo()` instead.
2. `stylesheet_directory` is one of these arguments where it is better just to use the function that is called by WordPress: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. It is easier to understand, especially in this case where one could expect a path by looking at the name of the argument string.
3. If you are using an URL provided by a WordPress function, **escape it**. Always.
4. For better readability, I would use `printf()` here.

Summary

```
printf( 
    '<img src="%s/img/ogpimage.png" alt="Blog Posts Placeholder">',
    esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() )
);
```